# NestJS, Vue and nginx in different docker containers gives an CORS error

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx, nestjs

NestJS container with enabled CORS:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as cors from 'cors';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }));

  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  await app.listen(8802);
}

bootstrap();
```

Vue container with requests to adress: `https://api:8802`

Error messages:

```
In Firefox:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource
```

```
In Chrome:
net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I tried everything and nothing works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the NestJS [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/cors), you should be able to use:

```
app.enableCors();
```

Or:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });
```

Instead of:

```
app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }));
```

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. I tried and ```app.enableCors();``` too. Same error

Comment: What happens if you try `http://localhost:8802/` using postman ?

Comment: It works. Through the postman or another rest client all the requests are working

Comment: have you tried `app.enableCors({ origin: "api:8802"})` or `app.enableCors({ origin: "/"})`

Comment: No. I though that ```app.enableCors({ origin: '*' })``` will work always. I will try